# Lottie animation appears later than the rest of the interface

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, lottie

I'm writing an application in compose and using Lottie animations. But there is such a problem: lottie animation appears later than the rest of the interface (buttons, lists etc.)

Is it normal or how to fix it?
I would be very grateful!

```
@Composable
fun MenuScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(top = 30.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Banner()
        StartButton()
        AlphabetGrid()
    }
}

@Composable
fun Banner(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val bannerLottieComposition by rememberLottieComposition(LottieCompositionSpec.RawRes(R.raw.menu_banner))

    LottieAnimation(
        composition = bannerLottieComposition,
        modifier = modifier
            .height(270.dp)
    )
}
```

Comment: You should provide some code when you ask for help in the community.

Comment: Sorry. I added my code

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the image source and the size of the json. If its too large then it can take a little bit of time to load. Moreover, if the asset source is somewhere in the remote server, then it can be an issue too.
So its good to use them locally and modify the json as needed.

You can try this. It solves most of the case.

```
animationView.setRenderMode(RenderMode.HARDWARE)
// Lottie Version 3.2.0
```

Comment: But how do this in compose?